# Where can i find a text editor plugin that can accept a variable

Tags: php, jquery

I don't know how to call this but here is the picture:

[image]

See the [higher quality image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81qMl.jpg).

I saw it in some website and what to create a report where the value that I get in the database will be pass to that plugin (*don't know what to call that*).

In the picture above. What do you call that? is it possible to pass php variable to that? For example, I have a value of:

```
$hello = "<b>hello</b>";
```

Can I pass that value to the plugin above? So the value of the plugin will be `Hello` but its bold?

Comment: What you have a picture of is a [*Mail Merge Template Editor* in Webform format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/word-mail-merge-a-walk-through-the-process-HA001034920.aspx). If you're unfamiliar with what that does, read that Office article; a lot of mail merge is done with Word and Access or Excel (think of the mid-range local or regional junk mail you get). I think the editor is [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all i did not understood how the title of the question is related to your question about the puling you displayed..

What yo have above is a rich text editor.. it's a WYSIWYG editor of html..
you have tons of plugins like that the most oppulr would be [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Comment: Sorry i realy dont know how to call that. ahm can i pass a php variable to that plugin?

Comment: a variable that contains a text string ?.. yes you can..  see the documentation .. and please chage the title of your question to be more informative .. *suggestion* "Where can i find a text editor plugin that can accept a variable"